# v-data-table can't get user list data from API using Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, backend

I need to show the user list in a data table, but it says no data available. What do I need to do to make it work?

This is my userDirectory page, only added a subheader and a data table which I got from Vuetify

```
<template>
  <div class="userDirectory">
    <v-subheader class="d-flex justify-space-between align-center">
      <h3>User Directory</h3>
    </v-subheader>
    <v-row>
      <v-card>
        <template>
          <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="users" :items-per-page="5" class="elevation-1"></v-data-table>
        </template>
      </v-card>
    </v-row>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
    {
            text: 'User ID',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'u.id',
          },
          { text: 'Created At', value: 'created_at' },
          { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
          { text: 'Is Premium', value: 'is_premium' },
          { text: 'Goal', value: 'goal' },
          { text: 'Fitness Level', value: 'fitness_level' },
          { text: 'Profile Completed', value: 'profile_completed' },
          { text: 'Accepted Health Warning', value: 'accepted_health_warning' },
          { text: 'Role', value: 'roles_list' },
    ],
    users: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    async loadUsers() {
      axios.get('https://somehost/api/admin/getUserList', { headers: {Authorization : 'Bearer ' + 'token' }})
      .then(res=> console.log(res))
  .catch(err=> console.log(err))
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

and this is the API file. I can get the data by making a GET request in Thunder Client, with a bearer token but the same token doesn't work in Vue.

```
const { response } = require("express");
const pool = require("../../config/database");

async function listUsers() {

    let sqlquery = `select
                        u.id, 
                        created_at,
                        email,
                        is_premium,
                        goal,
                        fitness_level,
                        profile_completed,
                        accepted_health_warning,
                        group_concat(r.name) as roles_list
                    from users u
                    left join user_role ur on ur.user_id = u.id
                    left join role r on r.id = ur.role_id
                    group by u.id;`
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(sqlquery,
            (error, results) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error)
                }
                return resolve(results)
            })
    })
}

module.exports.listUsers = listUsers;
```

Comment: In your then() what do you have for the `console.log(res)`

Comment: @RaphaelRollet actually, I get nothing. It doesn't print anything. And when I inspected the page, I get blocked by the CORS. Can these two be related?

Comment: I updated this comment and post a response to have a nice format and better understand

Answer (score 1):

Do you, at any point, call the `loadUsers` function?

```html
<script>
export default { 
  // ... data
  created() {
    this.loadUsers();
  }, 
  methods: {
    loadUsers() {
      axios.get('https://somehost/api/admin/getUserList', { headers: {Authorization : 'Bearer ' + 'token' }})
      .then(res=> {
          // assign the result to the users array
          this.users = res;
       })
      .catch(err=> console.log(err))
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I wasn't calling it, no. I updated my code with your snippet. It still doesn't work though but I realized that CORS policy was blocking my access. I am trying to solve it, other than that there is no progress.

Answer (score 1):

Like Matt say, you need to call your function, if you don't nothing happend.

```js
created() {
    this.loadUsers();
  },
```

But indeed (if you call it now) the cors failed the request and you don't get any responses. It's normal.

The server api where you do the request block the access and you got the cors error, i see in your file you require express, so i'm pretty sur you use express(nodejs).

You can try to install the node-cors package with the command:

```
npm install cors
```

Docs ir: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

In your app.js you do that:

```js
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://mywebsite.com'
}))
```

The origin is to authorize your vuejs app, so if your Vue app is running on `localhost:3000` or online on `mondomaine.com` you do this:

```
origin: 'http://mondomaine.com'
```

This solution works for online domain.

---

**In case you'r in localhost**, you have to setup a proxy on vue.js, it's not difficult.

In your case you have to replace the url when you get:

```js
axios.get('/api/admin/getUserList', ... // let what you have before
```

To understand, the call GET is now on `localhost:1000/api/admin/getUserList`, this call is on the same domain and doesn't work, but you don't have cors problem.

Now you have to setup a proxy, it's pretty easy!

```js
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api/*': {
        target: 'https://somehost/'
      }
    }
  },
```

Your call `localhost:1000/api/admin/getUserList` will trigger the proxy `^/api/*` and redirect this call to `https://somehost/api/admin/getUserList`

**Don't forget to restart you vue server after every update in vue.config.js.**

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation, unfortunately this didn't help. The vue.js is running on localhost, I don't know that would it work if it ran online.

Comment: @BurakSaraç i updated my response after the line `This solution works for online domain.`